# .NET Remoting - Question about RegisterWellKnownServiceType and activation of remote object

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I have 2 applications A1 and A2 with HttpChannel between them. Also there are 2 classes inherited from MarshalByRefObject - CObj1 and CObj2.

A1:

```
Cobj1 obj1 = new CObj1();

RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
                   typeof(CObj1), "CObj1", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

A2:

```
Cobj2 obj2 = new CObj2();

string _url = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/CObj1", host, port);

CObj1 remObj1 = ((CObj1)(Activator.GetObject(typeof(CObj1), _url)));

remObj1.Method1(obj2);
```

**The question is**: can I use obj2 in A1 after that? Do i need any RegisterWellKnown... for CObj2 even i do not need to get it by Activator.GetObject? In that scenario where is obj2 activated?

I am sorry but i could not find an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

- as far as i know , you can use the
  Obj2 on the server object method
  'Method1'. you dont need to any kind
  of activation.
- Keep in mid that the object -Obj2- is
  serialized on the client side, and
  then deserialized on the server, so
  its not exatly the same object.
- the changes on the object can be
  copied back and forth (using 'ref').

i hope this helps